# making greasemonkey GM_xmlhttpRequest once the page loads with

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am trying to create a script that will send a POST requests immediately after loading the web page .

The POST data parameter will contain certain values that it will collect via "document.getElementsByName"

here is what i am doing but it isnt working ---

```
var id1 = document.getElementsByName("ID1")[0].value

var id2 = document.getElementsByName("ID2")[0].value

GM_xmlhttpRequest({method: "POST",
  url: "https://www.example.com/",
  data: 'paramter1=' + id1 '&paramter2=' + id2 ,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  },
  onload: function(response) {
    console.log ("gut response");
    $("#input").get()[0].value=response.responseText;
  }
});
```

I will appreciate if @Brock Adams could answer

Comment: It will be extremely hard to help without knowing what website you are trying to POST to, but look at your `data` parameter, you may need to start with a `?` (i.e.) `www.example.com?parameter1=id1&parameter2=id2`

Comment: you can't use GM_ stuff after the page loads, you have to load another page, even if it's just a fake path that gm watches and that 404s normally. A hidden iframe is perfect for this.  You can then use GET params, cookies, localStorage, etc to pass the data to the new page that also runs the userscript, use a conditional to create "modes", or use a 2nd userscript on the hidden frame url.

Comment: @dandavis you said "You can then use GET params, cookies, localStorage, etc" , how exactly can we do that?